# Shared Preferences vs Database

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

My data is simple property values so I could store either way, but I was wondering which is more reliable?  Are shared preferences auto saved and therefore more reliable?  Or because they are non-transactional is that less reliable?

Answer (score 25):

The use of SharedPreferences or a ContentProvider/SQLite database is situation-based. In your situation, I would recommend using [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). A SQLite database is meant for potential hundreds of entries. SQLite database can also be queried and the data retrieval is much more robust. The SQLite database adds immense power to your entries. But in your case, I would recommend using `SharedPreferences`, unless you have the unusual need to sort/filter through your property values. They are both reliable services, `SharedPreferences` are not autosaved, you must use `commit()` to save changes. The SQLite database is a lot more structured than `SharedPreferences`. For more information check out [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).