# How to store a value in Android?

Tags: java, android, local-storage

I'm developing some apps, I need store the count of absents student for last day. I don't want to mess up with database. I need a way to store a integer and retrieve it after its next launch. Kindly help me

Comment: I would recommend you read up here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: heard anything about shared preferences?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shared Preferences vs Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988051/shared-preferences-vs-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use android SharedPreferences

For more details see below links:

[SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

[Android - Shared Preferences - tutorialspoin](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)