# Android - Feature flags from database, Shared preferences or memory?

Tags: android, performance, memory-efficient, featuretoggle

I'm curious about best practices here.

Currently, I save all the feature flags (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle) in the database. When I have to show some feature, I read the status (True/False) from it and then show/hide it depending on the value. There are a ton of these feature flags in my application and I'm constantly pinging the database throughout application.

Is there a better way? Saving it in database, but loading in cache (memory?) and reading from it? Updating that cache when something changes?

edit: Turning on/off is happening on the server side. Server then sync those changes to the application which is then saving it to the database.

Also, some pros/cons and memory impact of these options would be nice. Didn't find anything similar on the web.

Comment: We can use Shared preferences to store the key-value/flags (Small set of data), especially in a case of flag /app setting data database is not recommended.

Comment: Database is overkill- Shared prefferences should be better, but i have a question- Do you expect to be able remotelly to toggle feature, or each build have set those in advance

Comment: Edited question.

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988051/shared-preferences-vs-database) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276358/pros-and-cons-of-sqlite-and-shared-preferences) . SQLite would be overkill as you need to store simple key/value pairs, and the value is primitive boolean. Also you wont need to query big amount of data, as far as I understand you would only check for s single key at a time. Android is automatically caching the `SharedPreference` so you wont need to bother with that. 
Unless there isnt complex structure of values there is no point in using SQLite